# How to make a discord bot react to every message in a Discord channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make my bot react to every message in a discord channel `840211720470265887` but my script does not work as expected.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  client.channels.cache.get('840211720470265887');
    if (message.content === '') {
        message.react('✅');
    }
});
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for an empty message and if it is empty it will react to it. Remove the if statement that is checking for an empty message and it should react to all incoming messages in that spesific channel.

This is how you want it to look.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.id === '840211720470265887') {
        message.react('✅');
    }
});
```

Comment: but i want it to react to evey message like EVERY

Comment: Remove the if statement

Comment: well its working now but insted of that particular channel its reacting it in EVERY channel ;-;

Comment: Try with the code snippet i made in my answer